# RSpec request test - assign change the value before sending request with mock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've just noticed that after setting default values and can't change the value right before requesting.

When I check the value within the method handling this request, it shows `event.data.object.closed = false`.

Following code is just an example.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "stripe_invoice_created_webhook", type: :request do

  let(:invoice){ create(:invoice, account_id: account.id) }
  let(:account){ create(:account,
                        stripe_customer_id: event.data.object.customer)}
  let(:event){ StripeMock.mock_webhook_event('invoice.created', {
    closed: false
  }) }

  it 'responds 200 to invoice_created webhook with valid endpoint' do
    event.data.object.closed = true
    post '/stripe-events', event.as_json
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end    
end
```

Any ideas how to change the value right before sending some

## === update (Nov 17th 2016) ===========

The main question is **How can I change the mock value efficiently?**

I could write something like for each.

```
event = StripeMock.mock_webhook_event('invoice.created', {closed: true } )
```

It works, and the main question is how can I make it cleaner with `let(:foo)` as usual?

Comment: Can you share the code which you want to write test for?

Answer (score 0):

your `mock_webhook_event` is just a mock, a pseudo-response to the proper call. What you're trying to do is change the mock response on the fly as if it was the actual object.

Better (although slightly more verbose) would be to use a variable for the value

```
   let(:closed_response) {false}

   let(:event){ StripeMock.mock_webhook_event('invoice.created', {
    closed: closed_response
  }) }
```

Then in your test...

```
closed_response = true
post '/stripe-events', event.as_json
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but I still get the same result ... `false` value.

Comment: Are you referencing `event` before the `closed_response` assignment?  Once you reference it, the value for `:closed` is locked in.  You should set `closed_response = true` as the first line of your test.

Comment: `closed_response` assignment is at the top of the lines of a test block.

Comment: Is the test OK is you change the `let(:closed... ` to default to true?  It may be a problem in the test or code.